# Is there really any way to remove the Fog of War for Company of Heroes LAN mode?

Tags: company-of-heroes

I play Company of Heroes online using Game Ranger and have found sometimes that the opponent doing things which they should not be able to do. For example, in a match I remember the opponent was guessing exactly where my snipers were hiding and where my troops were standing even though I was in FOW and my Snipers were camouflaged.

After consulting with other pros I have heard that there is some kind of FOW reveal cheat code for Company of Heroes v 1.0

But I was never able to get my hands on it. Does anyone one know whether it really exists or not and where to find it?